# VB.net JSON(multiple data) deserialize into listbox

Tags: json, vb.net

I've a JSON response with 1-100 arrays of data. Please see the JSON result as follows:

```
[{
    "ts": 1529926023722.0,
    "val": {
        "channel_1": 253.0,
        "channel_2": 249.0
    }
}, {
    "ts": 1529926083770.0,
    "val": {
        "channel_1": 246.0,
        "channel_2": 249.0
    }
}, {
    "ts": 1529926143823.0,
    "val": {
        "channel_1": 246.0,
        "channel_2": 249.0
    }
}, {
    "ts": 1529926203874.0,
    "val": {
        "channel_1": 250.0,
        "channel_2": 255.0
    }
}]
```

The class for the JSON result should be:

```
Public Class Val
    Public Property channel_1 As Double
    Public Property channel_2 As Double
End Class

Public Class JSON_result
    Public Property ts As Double
    Public Property val As Val
End Class
```

For your reference, "ts" is unix time and i need to convert it into datetime, and insert it into the listbox (and also a chart graph) along with the Val (channel_1 and channel_2 accordingly).

The JSON_result has a maximum of 100 data, and i need it to loop each data with the unix-to-datetime conversion into the chart graph.

The chart graph data adding code is this:

```
ChartControl_module.Series("module_analog1").Points.Add(New DevExpress.XtraCharts.SeriesPoint(DateTime.Now, channel_1)) 

ChartControl_module.Series("module_analog2").Points.Add(New DevExpress.XtraCharts.SeriesPoint(DateTime.Now, channel_2))
```

I'd done the unix-to-datetime conversion function, it's working good. Just that i couldn't extract the channel_1 and channel_2 data to put it into the graph according to the relevant "ts". :(

How do i deserialize these multiple data of JSON result?

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization ' for reading of JSON (+add the reference to System.Web.Extensions library)
```

I would split the array so I could search whichever one I need.
Then you can grab values like this:

```
Dim JSONDictionary = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(Array1_JSON)
Dim Time = JSONDictionary("ts")
```

Alternatively if you want all at one place:

```
Dim JSONDictionary = New JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(JSON) ' you get 4 items, with subitems, grab what you want like JSONDictionary(3)("ts")
```